# About the MSDN code example, "Enabling and Disabling Privileges"

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

MSDN article, [Enabling and Disabling Privileges in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), provided a code example to show how to enable or disable a privilege in an access token.

I quote the part in questioned:

```
tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
if (bEnablePrivilege)
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
else
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;
```

**What is the meaning of the zero value for `Attributes` member?**

According to the documentation of [TOKEN_PRIVILEGES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, the attributes of a privilege can be a combination of the following values:

- `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED`  (it is **0x00000002L** in `WinNT.h`)
- `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT`  (it is **0x00000001L** in `WinNT.h`)
- `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED`  (it is **0x00000004L** in `WinNT.h`)
- `SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS`  (it is **0x80000000L** in `WinNT.h`)

So, we don't see any valid constant with a value of zero. I guess, the zero is equal to `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED`.

Once more, if the zero means disabling all privileges, I doubt it because disabling all privileges can be done simply by setting `DisableAllPrivileges` parameter of [AdjustTokenPrivileges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to `TRUE`.

Anybody here could explain what the zero value *really*  does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` was equivalent to zero it would be defined as such. Given the definitions that are there, I would suggest that a zero values means no privileges have ever been enabled, or subsequently used/removed: There are, and never have been, any token privileges.

Comment: So, zero means "disable", not "remove". Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference between *disabling* a privilege, which allows you to enable it again later, and *removing* a privilege from the token. Removing the privilege means that it *cannot* be later re-enabled.

Passing zero means that the `SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED` bit is not set, therefore that privilege is disabled.

Tokens contain a number of privileges when they're created. The `SeChangeNotifyPrivilege`, known as 'Bypass traverse checking' in the User Rights Assignment section of Local Security Policy/Group Policy, is always enabled by default, and shouldn't ever be disabled (see [KB823659](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823659#method3) for details). Therefore the `DisableAllPrivileges` parameter isn't actually useful.

User Account Control (Windows Vista and later) takes the raw logon token, clones it, and uses the `SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED` flag to create the 'filtered token' that is used to start the shell. The raw token is then hidden away so that the 'Run as Administrator' feature can use it to start programs.

You can see the privileges enabled in the process token using [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).